# Svn, how to repair missing branch-off

Tags: svn

in our subversion repository a branch was created, but not by using the "branch" method; instead copies of files from a local working copy were used to create a new branch directory. Can this be repaired afterwards?
So by example:

1. Checkout trunk/x r1234.
2. Copy files to new directory, make changes, commit this to a new
   directory branch/y, as r1357.
3. We are now at r1999 with many changes done both on trunk/x and
   branch/y.

Can we one way or another repair the missing link and register that branch/y(r1357) was actually branched off from trunk/x(r1234) and changed?